# R - Sliding Door Analysis # of events in time period

Tags: r, datetime, cluster-analysis, sliding-window, rollapply

I am reposting this question as I thought I needed a cluster type analysis but what is required is more of a 'sliding window' analysis. I have a dataset that has 59k entries recorded over 63 years, I need to identify 'clusters' of events with the criteria being:

A sequence of 6 or more events, with no more than a 6 hour period between consecutive events in the sequence.

Each event has a unique ID and a date/time stamp an output would ideally assign a cluster ID to events that fulfil the above criteria. I have been directed towards a sliding window appraoch, is the best option to use? maybe using rollapply from the zoo package?

I have added a sample one years worth of data if anyone is feeling in a very helpful mood.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16400709/StackOverflow/DataStack.csv

I have seen the output of such an analysis in R but have not been able to replicate it as of yet, the results of this analysis can be seen in this paper --> https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16400709/StackOverflow/fuhrmann_etal_waf2014.pdf

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution using `rollapply` from the `zoo` package.

```
require(chron)
require(zoo)

d <- read.csv("path/to/file/DataStack.csv")
d[] <- lapply(d, as.character)

d$time <- chron(d$Date, d$Time, format = c(dates = "d/m/y", times = "h:m:s"))
d <- d[order(d$time), ]
d$diffHours <- c(0, diff(d$time)) * 24
d$withinSixHr <- ifelse(d$diffHours < 6, 1, 0)
d$streak <- c(rep(NA, 5), rollapply(zoo(d$withinSixHr), width = 6, FUN = sum))
d$cluster <- ifelse(d$streak == 6, 1, 0)

d$clusterParticipant <- 0

for (i in 6:nrow(d)) {

  if (d[i, "cluster"] == 1) {

    d[i - 5, "clusterParticipant"] <- 1
    d[i - 4, "clusterParticipant"] <- 1
    d[i - 3, "clusterParticipant"] <- 1
    d[i - 2, "clusterParticipant"] <- 1
    d[i - 1, "clusterParticipant"] <- 1
    d[i - 0, "clusterParticipant"] <- 1

  }
}
```

And here's the result:

```
> head(d[c(1, 5:10)], n = 20)
   EventID                time   diffHours withinSixHr streak cluster clusterParticipant
2   272481 (01/01/11 00:02:00)   0.0000000           1     NA      NA                  1
3   272666 (01/01/11 00:40:00)   0.6333333           1     NA      NA                  1
4   272674 (01/01/11 00:46:00)   0.1000000           1     NA      NA                  1
5   272701 (01/01/11 01:15:00)   0.4833333           1     NA      NA                  1
6   272715 (01/01/11 02:00:00)   0.7500000           1     NA      NA                  1
7   272720 (01/01/11 02:25:00)   0.4166667           1      6       1                  1
8   272723 (01/01/11 02:56:00)   0.5166667           1      6       1                  1
21  278829 (09/01/11 03:25:00) 192.4833333           0      5       0                  0
1   268346 (17/01/11 10:03:00) 198.6333333           0      4       0                  0
43  280736 (25/01/11 15:35:00) 197.5333333           0      3       0                  0
26  279417 (25/01/11 17:15:00)   1.6666667           1      3       0                  1
44  280739 (25/01/11 17:41:00)   0.4333333           1      3       0                  1
45  280740 (25/01/11 18:08:00)   0.4500000           1      3       0                  1
46  280751 (25/01/11 18:40:00)   0.5333333           1      4       0                  1
47  280806 (25/01/11 19:09:00)   0.4833333           1      5       0                  1
48  281559 (25/01/11 21:50:00)   2.6833333           1      6       1                  1
14  276331 (01/02/11 06:10:00) 152.3333333           0      5       0                  0
15  276336 (01/02/11 08:24:00)   2.2333333           1      5       0                  0
50  281741 (01/02/11 20:06:00)  11.7000000           0      4       0                  0
11  275388 (24/02/11 15:53:00) 547.7833333           0      3       0                  0
```

EDIT: The code below is for giving each cluster (or supercluster) an ID number. It creates the variable `clusterDiff` and uses it as a switchboard to determine whether there's a change in cluster status. It'll be pretty slow on a large data set, but it'll do the trick.

```
d$clusterDiff <- c(d[1, "clusterParticipant"], diff(d$clusterParticipant))
d$clusterID <- as.numeric(NA)

count <- 1
inCluster <- FALSE

for (i in 1:nrow(d)) {

  if (d[i, "clusterDiff"] == 1) { 
    d[i, "clusterID"] <- count
    inCluster <- TRUE 

  } else if (d[i, "clusterDiff"] == -1) { 
    inCluster <- FALSE
    count <- count + 1

  } else if (inCluster == TRUE & d[i, "clusterDiff"] == 0) {
    d[i, "clusterID"] <- count

  } else { next }

}
```

Comment: Looks great, just going to give it a whirl over the full dataset and see how we get on. The above results look promising!

Comment: Hello, I have had a go at running the code, couple of quick q's, why do you have 'd[]' why would you not just call it 'd' never seen this before, when setting the data to d[] I get an error 'number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length' Also d <- d[order(d$time), ] throws an 'incorrect number of dimensions' error.  If I lapply just to d and do not order then I can get results down to d$cluster but the head() command does not print the same as above! Hope that makes sense?!

Comment: I've made a change that should read in the data for you correctly, and should take care of the errors you mentioned. Just change the file path to where you're keeping ```DataStack.csv```. I use ```d[]``` so that it preserves the data frame structure of ```d```, otherwise the result of ```lapply``` will be a list.

Comment: Reed thanks again, will give it another go. I have learnt more from stackoverflow than any book or online tutorial!

Comment: I learned that particular nugget from Hadley Wickham's excellent online (free) book, "Advanced R" (http://adv-r.had.co.nz/). Highly recommended if you have time to work through it.

Comment: I will take a look, okay got the code up and running time to run it through the full dataset and see how we go!

Comment: Just curious, what sort of "events" are we talking about here?

Comment: Tornadoes! I am looking at outbreaks, their cumulative energy looking for any correlation with the ENSO signal. The calculating energy expelled per outbreak and relationship with ENSO value was the easy bit. I have run and exported down to clusterpaticipant, will give this second step a shot now

Comment: Almost there, for ClusterParticipant, can the first cluster be 1, the second 2, 3, 4, 5.....off the top of my head define a loop say x and the if (d[i, "cluster"] == x) something like that!

Comment: Do you want adjacent clusters to be considered one big cluster, as in lines 7 and 8?

Comment: Correct....if the last tornado in the cluster occurs =>6 since the second last then they should be recorded as occurring within the same cluster. To think my supervisor was going to get me to do this in excel manually!

Comment: in other words a cluster is defined with 0s at the start and the end of a sequence of 1's in cluster participant, but ideally that sequence would then go 1, 2, 3 etc. That way I can generate unique cluster ID's

Comment: Ok I added a ```for``` loop that assigns cluster IDs. Your supervisor can buy me a beer next time I'm in London :D

Comment: IT WORKS...thats brilliant, yep a beer and might even get a thanks too in the write up!

Comment: Great :) if you wouldn't mind, post a copy of the report here if you decide to cite this post